# Determining Combinations of Variables Values that lead to a certain outcome

Tags: regression, machine-learning, combinatorics, statsmodels

Say I have a dataset with the following variables: age, gender and Impact. Impact is the dependent variable and it's binary, age and gender are independent variables numerical and binary respectively. For the dependent variable "impact", if there's an impact a value of 1 is assigned otherwise 0.
I want to find combinations of independent variables values that yield a value of 1 in the dependent variable. For example: age = 23 and gender= 1(female) or age = 30 and gender= 0(male).

Comment: Do you have a model of your data that's reasonably good?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You have the results and can look up which combinations gave impacts and which did not. What beyond that do you want?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies ! I will simulate the data most likely (anticipating an upcoming scenario, sort of a prophylactic move) , am I thinking about using Linear programming if statistics can't provide such insights. Any suggestions?